# Iterate over data in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, subquery, window-functions

Having this dataset: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6vmgx4krsgMRgprDjErdqu/0

I want to have a additional column which shows the time distance to the entry before, how can i achieve this?

Thank you very much in advance :)

Comment: What is precise MySQL version on YOUR server?

Comment: What do you mean by entry before - is that by customer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you stated in your fiddle that you use MySQL 5,7

You must use user defined variables.

I selected TIMEDIFF to display the difference because you didn't state which Information you need, so i choose this, but as you have both values you can use different mysql functions

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE `someTable` (
    `ID` INT,
    `POS` INT,
    `Date` DATETIME,
    `Customer` VARCHAR(64)
);

INSERT INTO `someTable` VALUES 
(1, 10, "2017-03-10 08:00:00", "Peter"), 
(2, 11, "2017-03-10 08:00:01", "Peter"),
(3, 12, "2017-03-10 08:00:04", "Peter"), 
(4, 17, "2017-03-10 08:00:05", "Peter"), 

(5, 16, "2017-03-10 08:00:08", "Karl"),
(6, 17, "2017-03-10 08:00:09", "Karl"),

(7, 10, "2017-03-10 08:00:12", "Peter"), 
(8, 10, "2017-03-10 08:00:13", "Peter");

SELECT * FROM someTable
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT 
ID,
POS
,`Customer`
,IF(@date = `Date`,0,TIMEDIFF(`Date`, @date)) diff
,@date := `Date` 'Date'
FROM someTable, (SELECT @date := (SELECT MIN(`Date`) FROM someTable)) A;

| ID  | POS | Customer | diff            | Date                |
| --- | --- | -------- | --------------- | ------------------- |
| 1   | 10  | Peter    | 0               | 2017-03-10 08:00:00 |
| 2   | 11  | Peter    | 00:00:01.000000 | 2017-03-10 08:00:01 |
| 3   | 12  | Peter    | 00:00:03.000000 | 2017-03-10 08:00:04 |
| 4   | 17  | Peter    | 00:00:01.000000 | 2017-03-10 08:00:05 |
| 5   | 16  | Karl     | 00:00:03.000000 | 2017-03-10 08:00:08 |
| 6   | 17  | Karl     | 00:00:01.000000 | 2017-03-10 08:00:09 |
| 7   | 10  | Peter    | 00:00:03.000000 | 2017-03-10 08:00:12 |
| 8   | 10  | Peter    | 00:00:01.000000 | 2017-03-10 08:00:13 |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6vmgx4krsgMRgprDjErdqu/0)

Answer (score 1):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, just use `lag()` and `timetstampdiff()`. Assuming that you want the date difference with the "previous" record of the same `customer`, and that it should be expressed in seconds:

```
select
    t.*,
    timestampdiff(
        second, 
        lag(date, 1, date) over(partition by customer order by date), 
        date
    ) diff_seconds
from sometable t
```

This gives a difference of `0` seconds for the first record of each group.

If you are running an earlier version, then I would recommend a correlated subquery. Although it might be a little less efficient than user variables, it is much safer, and future-proof (user variables are planned to be removed in a future version of MySQL):

```
select 
    t.*,
    timestampdiff(
        second, 
        coalesce((select max(t1.date) from sometable t1 where t1.customer = t.customer and t1.date < t.date), date), 
        date
    ) diff_seconds
from sometable t
```

For your sample data, [both queries return](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6vmgx4krsgMRgprDjErdqu/1):

```
| ID  | POS | Date                | Customer | diff_seconds |
| --- | --- | ------------------- | -------- | ------------ |
| 1   | 10  | 2017-03-10 08:00:00 | Peter    | 0            |
| 2   | 11  | 2017-03-10 08:00:01 | Peter    | 1            |
| 3   | 12  | 2017-03-10 08:00:04 | Peter    | 3            |
| 4   | 17  | 2017-03-10 08:00:05 | Peter    | 1            |
| 5   | 16  | 2017-03-10 08:00:08 | Karl     | 0            |
| 6   | 17  | 2017-03-10 08:00:09 | Karl     | 1            |
| 7   | 10  | 2017-03-10 08:00:12 | Peter    | 7            |
| 8   | 10  | 2017-03-10 08:00:13 | Peter    | 1            |
```

Answer (score -2):

Something like this outta do do the trick:

```
insert into @temp ([ID], [Date])
select
    t.[ID],
    datediff(day, Lag(t.[Date]) over(order by t.[Date]), t.[Date]) as [DateDiffFromPrevRow]
from someTable t

select
    t.[ID],
    t.[POS],
    t.[Date],
    t.[Customer],
    temp.[DateDiffFromPrevRow]
from sometable t
join @temp temp on temp.[ID] = t.[ID]
```

Comment: The question is [mysql]-tagged, not [sql-server].

Comment: also MySQL windows functions were introduced in MySQL version 8.0. 
The dbfiddle link was using MySQL 5.7 so he cannot even make use of LAG

Comment: o my bad, missed seeing the mysql tag